# JavaFX ListView - CellFactory styling

Tags: css, listview, javafx

I'm using a ListView with a CellFactory producing `Labels` for each list entry. When a list entry is **selected**, the text of the `Labels` becomes white no matter what `CSS` style i set for `list-view` or `list-cell`.

How can i controll the color/ styling behaviour of `Labels` used by a `CellFactory` aka `ListCell`?

```
items.addAll(Arrays.asList("Test 1","Test 2","Test 3"));
lstPreview.setItems(items);
lstPreview.setCellFactory(i -> new ListCell<String> () {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem (String item,boolean empty){
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(new Label(item));
                }
            }

    });
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to set graphic with `Label`, since the cell already has a `Labeled` which you can style directly: `setStyle(...); setId(...);` etc in updateItem method.

Comment: @Uluk Biy: Yes i can avoid the extra label in my example, but in real use i have complex layout containing `Labels` and other controll wrapped in e.g.`GridPanes` so i can't avoid `Labels` there....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply css to the `label`, when the list-cell is getting selected.

For a selected list-cell, the css is

```
.list-cell:filled:selected {
    ...
}
```

For a selected list-cell, which has a label, we can write

```
.list-cell:filled:selected .label {
    ...
}
```

To color the label, you can use `-fx-text-fill`

```
.list-cell:filled:selected .label {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

You can use the same way if it the content is any other node other than Label.

The output is as follows

[image]

**EDIT**

If you just want to override the default white color, you can override the `.label` on selected.

```
.list-cell:filled:selected .label {
    -fx-text-fill: black ;
}
```

Comment: But is there a way to prevent the default "white"-style to be applied?

Comment: Just override the default styling with your custom style. I have added an edit.